Snap lines to grid using ArcGIS Pro
I have a lines layer that I need to snap to a generated grid from the same layer:

The lines are pipes and the target is to simplify the lines to create a "diagram" following a grid:

I can achieve something similar by snapping the lines to the grid, but the issue is that I can't have lines crossing the grid, they have to be on the edge of the boxes:

Any ideas?

There's a number of ways you can can accomplish this, but all the ones I can think of involve Python. What have you tried?

Geopandas or Arcpy would be a good idea, I only tried in ArcGIS Pro desktop. But I would not know how to achieve this using python. Thanks for the help!

How about this as a work flow?

Convert your grid polygon dataset into a polyline dataset.
Split the polylines at their vertices, to create a set of 2-vertex polylines.
Create a Trace network from your 2-vertex polyline dataset.
Use the end points of your brown line layer as the start and end of a trace.

You could achieve most, if not all of this, using modelbuilder, so little to no code. Would require you to have at least an Advanced license in ArcPro.
